# Multiple values for single key

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have a list that contains Categories and their accept/reject counts but there is a problem with this list. I'm using a LINQ query to access the data, and I grouped them by both category name and Accept/Reject Code(ResultCode). So the data is in this form:

[image]

Almost all of the Categories have both AP counts and RJ counts. And what I'm trying to do is to show each Category's accept and reject count. What should I use? Hashtables don't fit in this problem, I tried Dictionary with int List as value but couldn't add when the same key appeared.

**UPDATE**:

```
List<ModReportingDM.ReportObjects.AllCategories> allcats = new List<ModReportingDM.ReportObjects.AllCategories>();
Dictionary<string, ModReportingDM.ReportObjects.ResultCode> dict = new Dictionary<string, ModReportingDM.ReportObjects.ResultCode>();
ModReportingDM.ReportObjects.ResultCode x = new ModReportingDM.ReportObjects.ResultCode();
allcats = reportBLL.GetAllCats(model.ModId, model.ReportStartDate, model.ReportEndDate);
        if (allcats != null)
        {
            model.AllCatsList = new List<ModReportingDM.ReportObjects.AllCategories>();

            foreach (var item in allcats)
            {
                x.Accepted = item.Count;
                x.Rejected = item.Count;
                dict.Add(item.Category, x);

            }
        }
```

Query:

```
public List<AllCategories> GetAllCats(int modId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        using (entities = new ModReportingEntities())
        {
            var query = (from c in entities.Content
                         where c.ModId == modId && c.CreatedTime >= startDate && c.CreatedTime <= endDate && c.Category != null
                         group c by new { c.Category, c.ResultCode } into g
                         orderby g.Count() ascending
                         select new AllCategories
                         {
                             Category = g.Key.Category,
                             ResultCode = g.Key.ResultCode,
                             AcceptCount = g.Count(),
                             RejectCount = g.Count()
                         });

            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could map your category as the key, and create a data structure which describes both AP and RJ.

Comment: I thought about it conceptually but apparently my data structures knowledge is quite insufficient. Thanks, I'll work on that.

Comment: See my answer for more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague and I realized that we can keep track of the Category's and if same Category occurs, it means that only a field of it should be changed(either AcceptCount or RejectCount). So we've created a lambda expression like this:

```
foreach(var item in allcats)
            {
                if (model.AllCategories.Select(m => m).Where(x => x.Category == item.Category).ToList().Count == 0) 
                {
                    if (item.ResultCode == "AP") {
                        model.AllCategories.Add(new ModReportingDM.ReportObjects.AllCategories()
                        {
                            Category = item.Category,
                            AcceptCount = item.Count
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        model.AllCategories.Add(new ModReportingDM.ReportObjects.AllCategories()
                        {
                            Category = item.Category,
                            RejectCount = item.Count
                        });
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    ModReportingDM.ReportObjects.AllCategories x = model.AllCategories.Select(n => n).Where(y => y.Category == item.Category).ToList().First();
                    if (item.ResultCode == "AP") 
                    {
                        x.AcceptCount = item.Count;
                    }
                    else 
                    { 
                        x.RejectCount = item.Count; 
                    }
               }   
            }
```

If same Category occurs, go ahead and change its AcceptCount or RejectCount accordingly. That's the way I solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

What i would do is create a `ResultCode` class:

```
public class ResultCode
{
    public int Ap { get; set; }
    public int Rj { get; set; }
}
```

and then use a `Dictionary<string, ResultCode>` which maps each category to its report.

You could also take a different approach using a `Tuple<T1, T2>` (which personally i like less) which simply maps your key to two distinct values:

```
Dictionary<string, Tuple<int, int>> categoryToResultCode;
```

Comment: When I did this, it gives  "An item with the same key has already been added." error, what do I wrong?

Comment: You first need to group all your values by category, and only create the class. Add the code which generates the dictionary.

Comment: What is `x` in your code? I don't see a LINQ query. Also, you're adding `item.Count` twice to both `Accepted` and `Rejected` variables?

Comment: Sorry, I just added the x part. LINQ query is done in the repository and GetAllCats() function returns the list that I showed in my question. But I'll add query too. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<Tuple<string, string, int>> listOfTuples = new List<Tuple<string, string, int>>();
            Tuple<string, string, int> tupleItem1 = new Tuple<string, string, int>("A", "AP", 1);
            listOfTuples.Add(tupleItem1);
```

You can use Tuple. Please refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx